# Use different static lib memory for win32 threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-local-storage

I have some old C static lib which have code similar to:

.h file

```
void setValue(int);
```

.c file

```
int value;

void setValue(int i) { value = i; }
```

and from main app (written with c++) it's just invoked by calling (there's extern C include in header file of course)

```
setValue(42);
```

In single thread everything works just fine and of course if use same lib in 2 different threads "value" is shared between them.

What would be best way to use separate memory for that lib for every thread?

so if there would be 2 threads T1 and T2, it would work like:

```
T1.setValue(1); 
T2.setValue(2);
T1.start();
T2.start();

// T1 works with value "1"
// T2 works with value "2"
```

Comment: It's not possible without changing the library to use *thread local data* for the variable.

Comment: It's possible if you do your own runtime linking and relocation. However it's not trivial and usually not worth the trouble.

Comment: I know that it doesn't work with static or shared libs, that's why I want to know what options are there. Thread locals would be one way, though in my case I have some legacy lib, that I can't change.

Comment: Calvin that sounds interesting (but more for fun :) ), I probably would better do a wrapper as separate process, then mess with linking

Comment: One simple think it's possible to do with dynamic loading is to rename (copy) dll to few files with different names and than load them via LoadLibrary().

Comment: Quite interesting think is that if rename dll and load all of them dynamically  , every will have its own memory.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can change and recompile the code, you can mark the `value` static variable with either [`__thread`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Thread-Local.html) or with `thread_local` (C++11) or with [`__declspec(thread)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb.aspx) (MSVC). Then each thread will have a separate storage for the variable.